# XSRF token and Laravel session have decode for base64 algorithm

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, base64, x-xsrf-token

after decode:

```
{
    "iv": "h3+O3H421A5OSLU8DF43tA==",
    "value": "c9YNMmwBIdkkKin2Z4C7FqZJu13Mk1xPz0NiOSfhiPk=",
    "mac": "7a03cb1f0b3b246bc9cdbc573c070dc7e7fad15f1da27014e899a89fc6b0c0ce"
}
```

i am trying to prevent this decoding .. could not show iv , value and mac... anyone can help?

Comment: If you have the token, you can make the request. The actual decoding doesn't make it any less safe.

Comment: yes your are right but any method can i use to iv , value and mac not show